# Drawing lines to create a Cell in Java

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a DFS generated maze. I started by making a `Cell` object that has 4 lines (Top, Right, Bottom and Left). I then drew these lines on to a Maze `JPanel`. My problem is that most of the cells look fine but the left and top side of the `JPanel` have thick lines and I can't figure out how to make it just a regular grid.

Here is my `Cell` where I create the lines:

```
boolean[] walls = {true, true, true, true};

// Draw the lines of one cell with w width and h height
void drawCell(Graphics g, int w, int h){

    // Set the color of the lines to white
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    // If the top wall exists draw a top line
    if (walls[0]) {
        g.drawLine(TopLeftX(), TopLeftY(), TopRightX(w), TopRightY());
    }
    // If a right wall exists draw a right line
    if (walls[1]) {
        g.drawLine(TopRightX(w), TopRightY(), BotRightX(w), BotRightY(h));
    }
    // If a bottom wall exists draw a bottom line
    if (walls[2]) {
        g.drawLine(BotRightX(w), BotRightY(h), BotLeftX(), BotLeftY(h));
    }
    // If a left wall exists draw a left line
    if (walls[3]) {
        g.drawLine(BotLeftX(), BotLeftY(h), TopLeftX(), TopLeftY());
    }
}

// Set each coordinate for the lines, these will make a square that
// is w wide and h high
private int TopLeftX()      { return i;      }
private int TopLeftY()      { return j;      }
private int TopRightX(int w){ return i * w;  }
private int TopRightY()     { return j;      }
private int BotRightX(int w){ return i * w;  }
private int BotRightY(int h){ return j * h;  }
private int BotLeftX()      { return i;      }
private int BotLeftY(int h) { return j * h;  }
```

`w` is the width of a cell and `h` is the height.

And here is my `MazeView` `JPanel` where I draw the lines:

```
class MazeView extends JPanel{

    private Cell grid[][];
    private Cell cell;

    private int row;
    private int col;

    private int width = 600;
    private int height = 580;

    // Create a maze view JPanel that is rows tall and cols wide
    MazeView(int rows, int cols){
        super.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        super.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols));

        newGrid(rows, cols);
    }

    // Paint all the cells
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Get the height and width of each cell
        int h = height / getRows();
        int w = width / getCols();

        // Loop to draw each cell
        for (int i = 0; i <= getRows(); i++){
            for (int j = 0; j <= getCols(); j++){

                grid[i][j].drawCell(g, w, h);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help I can get.

When this is run my grid looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUDms.png]

Comment: I am not gettting what you mean with "thick" lines. Could it be that you are simply drawing "half" a maze square there?

Comment: Since your panel has a black background that white border might not be the panel but something else. Try to debug that with some other color (suggestion: have a look at MiGLayout which IMO is one of the best swing layout managers and has a debug render option). Addionally, using `GridLayout` and rendering the cells yourself looks like a code smell, i.e. either do the layout entirely (and thus use `null` layout) or do use components (e.g. JLabels) for the cells.

Comment: I don't think so because it is drawing most of the grid perfectly. The picture link at the bottom shows the edges of the Panel that seem like the lines are being drawn on thick.

Comment: That looks nothing like a maze to me so I'm not really sure what you are trying to do. I would guess you get thick lines because two edges of related squares each paint a line. Instead of creating a large grid start with something simple. Maybe 2 squares. See what happens when you paint them side by side with/without walls.

Comment: 1) Tip: Add @GhostCat (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: @camickr Well it isn't a maze yet. Im starting by drawing each cell then when I start DFS at a Cell and go to a neighbor the wall between the two will be removed. I did start by drawing just a few squares and it worked. Then this happened when I tried changing them to lines.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Ill do that. Sorry I'm very new to Java so still learning.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at  `g.drawLine(TopLeftX(), TopLeftY(), TopRightX(w), TopRightY());` - resolving the values of those methods you get coordinates `i, j, i*w, j`. Assuming that `i` and `j` are the cell positions you'll draw a line

- for cell 0/0 from 0/0 to 0/0
- for cell 1/0 from 1/0 to w/0
- for cell 0/1 from 0/1 to 0/1
- for cell 2/2 from 2/2 to 2*w/2

etc.

Thus you'll want to correct your coordinate calculation for all 4 draw commands. 
Assuming `i` and`j` are the cell's grid coordinates and `w` and `h` are the dimensions of the cell the coordinates for the top left corner would then be `i * w` and `j * h` and for the bottom right corner `(i + 1) * w` and `(j + 1) * h`.

Example:

```
     0   3   6   9
     --------------> x

0 |  +---+---+---+
  |  |0/0|1/0|2/0|
3 |  +---+---+---+
  |  |0/1|1/1|2/1|
6 |  +---o---+---+ 
  |  |0/2|1/2|2/2|
9 |  +---+---O---+ 
  V
  y
```

Let's assume each cell has a width and hight of 3 pixels. Thus the coordinates for the bottom center cell are:

- top left (`o`): `x = i * w = 1 * 3 = 3` and `y = j * h = 2 * 3 = 6`
- bottom right (`O`): `x = (i + 1) * w = (1 + 1) * 3 = 6` and `y = (j + 1) * h = (2 + 1) * 3 = 9`.

Answer (score 0):

> Well it isn't a maze yet. Im starting by drawing each cell

Don't fully grasp what you are attempting, but I would think a cell needs to be different colors, not lines. So for example a white cell is a place a player can move to. A black cell is a wall. I'm not sure how drawing individual line will make a maze?

> I am trying to create a DFS generated maze.

Don't know what that is, but here is some old code that might give you some ideas.

This is designed to be a maze and you paint icons (instead of colors as I suggested above) for each cell. In this basic implementation you only have two types of icons:

1. a floor
2. a wall

A file containing 0/1 is used to identify each cell and therefore the icon of the cell

You then have a playing piece that can move from floor to floor and is blocked when it hits a wall.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.io.*;

public class SmallWorld extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener
{

    //WORLD
    String[][] worldArray = new String[30][30];

    //Block colors
    private static Color redBlock = new Color(255,0,0,255);
    private static Color whiteBlock = new Color(255,255,255,255);
    private static Color blackBlock = new Color(0,0,0,150);

    //World images
//  JLabel wall = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("wall.gif") );
//  JLabel floor = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("floor.gif") );
    ImageIcon wallIcon = new ImageIcon("dukewavered.gif");
    ImageIcon floorIcon = new ImageIcon("copy16.gif");

    //Starting coordinates
    int blockPositionX = 1;
    int blockPositionY = 1;

    //Typing area to capture keyEvent
    JTextField typingArea;
    //Viewable area
    JViewport viewable;
    String type = "";

    JLayeredPane layeredPane;
    JPanel worldBack;
    JPanel panel;
    JPanel player;
    Dimension worldSize = new Dimension(1500, 1500);

    public SmallWorld() {
        super( );

        createWorld();
        layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        add(layeredPane);
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize( worldSize );

        worldBack = new JPanel();
        layeredPane.add(worldBack, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        worldBack.setLayout( new GridLayout(30, 30) );
        worldBack.setPreferredSize( worldSize );
        worldBack.setBounds(0, 0, worldSize.width, worldSize.height);
        worldBack.setBackground( whiteBlock );

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
                JPanel square = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
                worldBack.add( square );
                type = worldArray[i][j];
                if ( type.equals("1") )
                {
                    square.add( new JLabel(wallIcon) );
                }
                else
                {
                    square.add( new JLabel(floorIcon) );
                }
            }
        }

        //Draw the player
        player = new JPanel();
        player.setBounds(50, 50, 50, 50);
        player.setBackground( Color.black );
        player.setLocation(50, 50);
        layeredPane.add(player, JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER);
        //set where the player starts
//      panel = (JPanel)worldBack.getComponent( 31 );
//      panel.add( player );

        //Create the typing area with keyListener, add to window
        typingArea = new JTextField(20);
        typingArea.addKeyListener(this);
        typingArea.setEditable( false );
        add(typingArea);
    }

    //Get the world from the DAT file and translate it into
    //a 2d array to be used by paintComponent
    public void createWorld() {
        String getData = null;
        int countRow = 0;

        try {
            //Get file
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("world.dat");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            getData = new String();
            //read each line from file, store to 2d array
            while ((getData = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if(countRow < 30) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                        String temp = "" + getData.charAt(i);
                        worldArray[countRow][i] = temp;
                    }
                countRow++;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Uh oh, got an IOException error!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //Move Block around the world
    public void moveBlock() {
        Point pt = new Point();
        pt.x = blockPositionX * 50;
        pt.y = blockPositionY * 50;

        int x = Math.max(0, pt.x - 250);
        int y = Math.max(0, pt.y - 250);
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x, y, 550, 550);
        scrollRectToVisible( r );
    }
    //check for collisions with blocks
    public boolean checkCollision(int row, int col) {
        if ( worldArray[col][row].equals("1") ) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        updateView( e );
        e.consume();
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }

    //Update the view of the window based on which button is pressed
    protected void updateView( KeyEvent e ) {
        //if UP
        if ( e.getKeyCode() == 38 ) {
            if ( checkCollision( blockPositionX, blockPositionY - 1 ) == false ) {
                blockPositionY = blockPositionY - 1;
                moveBlock();
                player.setLocation(blockPositionX *50, blockPositionY*50);
            }
        }
        //if DOWN
        if ( e.getKeyCode() == 40 ) {
            if ( checkCollision( blockPositionX, blockPositionY + 1 ) == false ) {
                blockPositionY = blockPositionY + 1;
                moveBlock();
                player.setLocation(blockPositionX *50, blockPositionY*50);
            }
        }
        //if LEFT
        if ( e.getKeyCode() == 37 ) {
            if ( checkCollision( blockPositionX - 1, blockPositionY ) == false ) {
                blockPositionX = blockPositionX - 1;
                moveBlock();
                player.setLocation(blockPositionX *50, blockPositionY*50);
            }
        }
        //if RIGHT
        if ( e.getKeyCode() == 39 ) {
            if ( checkCollision( blockPositionX + 1, blockPositionY ) == false ) {
                blockPositionX  = blockPositionX + 1;
                moveBlock();
                player.setLocation(blockPositionX *50, blockPositionY*50);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SmallWorld");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JComponent newContentPane = new SmallWorld();
        newContentPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(1500, 1500) );
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( newContentPane );
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(568, 568) );
        frame.getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setResizable( false );
        //frame.setSize(500,520);
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You will need a couple of small icons to represent the floor/wall.

You will also need a file to represent the maze. Here is an example "world.dat" file:

```
111111111111111111111111111111
100010001010001000101000100011
100010001010001000101000100011
100011101010000000001000000001
100010000010000000001000000001
100110000010000000001000000001
100000000010000000001000000001
111100011110000000001000000001
100000000110001110111000111011
100000000000001110111000111011
100000000000000000000000000001
100010001110000000000000000001
100010001110001110111000111011
100011101100000000000000000011
100010000110001110111000111011
100110000100000000000000000011
100000000110000000001000000001
111100011100000000000000000011
100000000100000000000000000011
100000000010000000000000000001
100000000010000000000000000001
100010000000000000000000000001
100010000000001110111000111011
100011101110000000011000000001
100010000110000000011000000001
100110000110000000001000000001
100000000110001110111000111011
111100011110000000011000000001
100000000110000000011000000001
111111111111111111111111111111
```