I'm trying to draw a 2d tile map from a .txt file in java but it is only using one of the tiles accross the map and not using whats in the .txt file
I'm following a java 2d game tutorial from ryisnow on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugzxCcpoSdE
I was able to display each tile on its own but I don't know why the .txt isnt working
here is the map01.txt package
1001111111111111
1000000000000001
1000000000000001
1000000000000001
1000000000000001
1000000000000001
1000000000000001
1000002222000001
1000002222000001
1000002222000001
1000002222000001
1111111111111111


this is my Tile.java package
package tile;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Tile {

    public BufferedImage image;
    public boolean collision = false;
}


this is my TileManager.java
package tile;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import main.GamePanel;

public class TileManager {

    GamePanel gp;
    Tile[] tile;
    int mapTileNum[][];
    
    public TileManager(GamePanel gp) {
    
        
        this.gp = gp;
        
        tile = new Tile[10];
        mapTileNum = new int[gp.maxScreenCol][gp.maxScreenRow];
        
        getTileImage();
        loadMap();
    }
    
    public void getTileImage() {
        
        try {
            
            tile[0] = new Tile();
            tile[0].image = ImageIO.read(getClass ().getResourceAsStream("/tiles/Grass.png"));
            
            tile[1] = new Tile();
            tile[1].image = ImageIO.read(getClass ().getResourceAsStream("/tiles/Wall.png"));
            
            tile[2] = new Tile();
            tile[2].image = ImageIO.read(getClass ().getResourceAsStream("/tiles/Water.png"));
            
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void loadMap() {
        
        try {
            InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/maps/map01.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(is));
            
            int col = 0;
            int row = 0;
            
            while(col < gp.maxScreenCol && row < gp.maxScreenRow) {
                 
                String line = br.readLine();
                
                while(col < gp.maxScreenCol) {
                    
                    String numbers[] = line.split(" ");
                    
                    int num = Integer.parseInt(numbers[col]);
                    
                    mapTileNum[col][row] = num;
                    col++;
                }
                if(col == gp.maxScreenCol) {
                    col = 0;
                    row++;
                }
            }
            br.close();
            
        }catch(Exception e) {
            
        }
        
        
        
        
        
        
    }
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
        
        int col = 0;
        int row = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        
        while(col < gp.maxScreenCol && row < gp.maxScreenRow) {
            
            int tileNum = mapTileNum[col][row];
            
            g2.drawImage(tile[tileNum].image, x, y, gp.tileSize, gp.tileSize, null);
            col++;
            x += gp.tileSize;
            
            if(col == gp.maxScreenCol) {
                col = 0;
                x = 0;
                row++;
                y += gp.tileSize;
            }
        }
    }

}

and here is my GamePanel.java package
package main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import entity.Player;
import tile.TileManager;


public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{

    
    // SCREEN SETTINGS
    final int originalTileSize = 16; // 16x16 tile
    final int scale = 3;
            
    public final int tileSize = originalTileSize * scale; // 48x48 tile
    public final int maxScreenCol = 16;
    public final int maxScreenRow = 12;
    public final int screenWidth = tileSize * maxScreenCol; // 768 pixels
    public final int screenHeight = tileSize * maxScreenRow; // 576 pixels
    
    // FPS
    int FPS = 60;
    
    
    TileManager tileM = new TileManager(this);
    KeyHandler keyH = new KeyHandler();
    Thread gameThread;
    Player player = new Player(this,keyH);
    

    public GamePanel() {
        
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth, screenHeight));
        this.setBackground(Color.white);
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        this.addKeyListener(keyH);
        this.setFocusable(true);
    }

    public void startGameThread() {
        
        gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();
    }


    @Override
//  public void run() {     
//      
//      double drawInterval = 1000000000/FPS; //0.0166666 seconds
//      double nextDrawTime = System.nanoTime() + drawInterval;
//      
//      while(gameThread != null) { 
//                      
//
//          
//          // UPDATE: update information such as character positions
//          update();
//          
//          // 2 DRAW: draw the screen with the update information
//          repaint();
//          
//          
//          try {
//              double remainingTime = nextDrawTime - System.nanoTime();
//              remainingTime = remainingTime/1000000;
//              
//              if(remainingTime < 0) {
//                  remainingTime = 0;
//              }
//              Thread.sleep((long) remainingTime);
//              
//              nextDrawTime += drawInterval;
//              
//          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//              e.printStackTrace();
//          }
//      }
//      
//  }
    
        
    public void run() {
        
        double drawInterval = 1000000000/FPS;
        double delta = 0;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long currentTime;
        long timer = 0;
        int drawCount =0;
        
        while(gameThread != null) {
            
            currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            
            delta += (currentTime - lastTime) / drawInterval;
            timer += (currentTime - lastTime);
            lastTime = currentTime;
            
            if(delta >= 1) {
                update();
                repaint();
                delta--;
                drawCount++;
            }
            
            if(timer >= 1000000000) {
                System.out.println("FPS:" + drawCount);
                drawCount = 0;
                timer = 0;
            }
            
        }
    }
    
        
    public void update() {
        
        player.update();

    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        Graphics2D g2= (Graphics2D)g;
        
        tileM.draw(g2);
        
        player.draw(g2);
        
        g2.dispose();
    }

    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
}

I thought I had followed the tutorial correctly but its not following the text file.
what it should look like:

what mine looks like:


but I don't know why the .txt isnt working - no idea what "not working" means. Post an image of what you get and what you expect to get. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46981554/131872 for a simple example of a maze that might help.

So I'm guessing the "blue area" is the part that should be generated from parsing your text file?
It would be nice if you explicitly stated this in your question.
String numbers[] = line.split(" ");

Doesn't look to me like you have any spaces in your text file.
I would guess the code should be:
String numbers[] = line.split("");

Or, did you look at the working code I provided you in my initial comment to see how I parsed the text file? It never hurts to look at multiple solutions to a problem.

Thank you that was it. in the tutorial he specifically says to put a space in the quotations but never says he put a space in the text file. when he was typing in to the text grid it looked like there was more space between each number but I thought it was just some format setting he was using to be able to see the grid better.

In your map01.txt just add spaces in each numbers

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
